# GPL-3.0 based code in proprietary web application

Tags: open-source, gpl

I am creating a website in php for one of my client. i wanted to use few piece of code from a Open source code based on GPL-3.0 license. e.g i wanted to use validation code from that lib and modify the 30% of the code for my requirements.

Only my client will be using that software and i will provide him complete source code as well.

Is it ok to use GPL 3.0 code in this way?

Comment: One thing to consider is who uses the website your client has? If part of the GPLv3 code is javascript (or executed in the user browser somehow) that might extend the requirement of distributing the code further than your client might like. If all users of the site are employees of the client then they should be ok. If outsiders are supposed to use the site, then they might have a claim to all the code, not just the GPLv3 code. (IANAL but this has not be established by courts so far).

Comment: @Bent For what it's worth, [the FSF is of the opinion that the Javascript we normally execute in our browsers fails to qualify as "source code"](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.en.html), and they have [very specific advice on how to make your JS code "free"](https://www.gnu.org/software/librejs/free-your-javascript.html).

Comment: Sencha does not agree on that, but they might be wrong legally: https://www.sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq/ look for "What is the Sencha interpretation of “conveyance” under the GPL v3?"

Answer (score 6):

That is completely fine as long as you do not impose any restrictions on what the client can do with the source code you give them (other than the ones imposed by the GPL itself).

Specifically, since the GPL requires that your modified version has to also be licensed under the GPL when you distribute it, your client must have the freedom to make their own modified versions, use them for anything they want, and distribute them to anyone they want, for free or for a fee. That includes at least the theoretical possibility of something like the client adding more features on their own and then trying to sell their improved version to you or your competitors. As long as you don't plan on restricting any of those behaviors (aside from the GPL restrictions that they also provide source code and a copy of the GPL and so on if they do that), you're fine.

Just remember to include a complete copy of the GPL license alongside the source code you give to this client, and state in the Readme that the code is being distributed under that license.

Comment: so thing is, client is a big brand and this would be proprietary to him only, so no option to sell to another client etc. He will only be using it for his company.  Is it ok to skip including the GPL license as i am not using complete GPL only few source files.

Comment: 1) It is absolutely not okay to skip including the GPL license. No exceptions there, short of getting the GPL'd code out of your program. 2) When you say the code is "proprietary to him only" so there's "no option to sell", are you saying your code integrates with systems unique to that one client so there would be no point in them giving the code to anyone else? Or are you asking about *preventing* the client from selling the code if for some bizarre reason they try to do so? The former is totally fine, the latter is not.

Comment: @Techmaster Incidentally, the FSF has [a very good FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html) that covers a lot of these issues, so it may help to read through that and some of the other pages it links to.

Comment: Yes my code integrates with his some propriety services and unique systems so no point in them giving the code to anyone else.

Comment: @Techmaster Cool, then you should be fine as long as you include the license.

Comment: Cool, at least until the company gets sold, or sells off the unit using the code, or something like that.  Those are conveyance events too.  Just because they weren't anticipated, doesn't mean they won't happen. Those sorts of things are especially common in "big brand" companies.

Answer (score 5):

GPL and Proprietary are opposite licenses.  GPL guarantees that everyone can see the source code, modify it, and distribute it so long as they distribute it and any modifications under the GPL.  Proprietary means that you don't share the source code, allow other people to modify it, or allow people to distribute your code.

The FSF recommends using GPL3 everywhere.  "Can I put GPL3 code in my proprietary project?"  Yes, but only if you make your whole project GPL3 *instead of* proprietary.

I think you meant to ask, "Can I distribute GPL3 code in a proprietary project and still keep it proprietary?"  The answer to that is *No*.  Some open-source licenses are compatible with that: Apache, Eclipse, MIT, and BSD.  GPL or LGPL can be used in this way too, but only with the "[classpath-exception](https://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/license.html)".

Now, if you run the code on your own servers in a web app, you are not distributing it, and thus don't kick in all the provisions of the GPL.  As soon as you distribute it to someone else though, all those provisions of the GPL apply.  If you want to write code that behaves like the GPL even without distribution, you want the Affero-GPL license.

Answer (score 1):

GPLv3 and proprietary code do not mix.  This is by-design.

The interpretation of GPLv3 as I've understood it is that your codebase can remain closed (and private) if...

- you host and operate the code yourself, because you are not distributing the source to anyone.
- if the code was built on a work-for-hire basis, in which case the company who hired you legally created it (not you.)

Once you hand off the source or create an installation that a third-party can use for themselves, be they the client or whomever, then you are required to open-source your code under the GPLv3 too.

Personally (and based on legal advice) I don't use GPLv3 code unless I plan to make an open source application.